# postgres server not running in flask

Tags: python, postgresql, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to put command python run.py but it is always showing this error. What should I do?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYB1J.png)

Comment: (a) Please don't post *pictures* of text. Include the text in your question, properly formatted.

Comment: (b) The error says that SQLAlchemy is unable to connect to your postgres server. Can you tell us more about your environment? Are you running a postgres server somewhere?

Comment: I am using postgres in a flask project.

Comment: But *how* are you running postgres?  How are you starting it?  Where is it running? Is is on the same host as your flask project?  Ideally, rather than responding in comments, update your question to include more information, and replace the image link with the actual text of your error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a progreSql user but I faced the same problem with mysql some days ago and I just run a command to start mysql and it works!

it looks like your database is not started.

I found this in [progres documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/server-start.html) for starting the database :

```
postgres -D /usr/local/pgsql/data
```

the path can be changed with the exact path of your progess installation folder